# What is UITableViewController.RowsInSection(UITableView, int) supposed to be in Xamarin.iOS?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, uitableview

I have subclassed a `UITableViewController` and at some point wanted to find out the number of rows in a section. I wanted to use:

```
myController.TableView.NumberOfRowsInSection(2);
```

instead (thanks to Intellisense) I typed:

```
myController.RowsInSection(myController.TableView, 2);
```

The first method returns the correct number of rows. The latter one however always returns zero. I then looked up Apple's documentation and there is no such method on `UITableViewController`.

Is this a bug or a feature I don't understand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the method of the `UITableViewDataSource` class. It basically makes the `UITableViewController` conform to the `UITableViewDataSource` Obj-C protocol and it is meant to be overridden, not called directly.

So, instead of creating a separate class for the table source, you can use the table controller for the same purpose.

Example:

```
// Inside your UITableViewController subclass.
// Instead of this:
//this.TableView.Source = new MyTableSource();
// You can do this:
this.TableView.WeakDataSource = this;
this.TableView.WeakDelegate = this;
```

Comment: I see. They should add proper documentation to these methods. Can be quite annoying for a beginner to track down an issue caused by this misunderstanding.